# display two layouts

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to build a program where users data is displayed in table view while Home,About and Settings are to be displayed in TabLayout just below the table layout but TabLayout is not shown on screen while program runs. Here I have two class file one to display table layout whereas another to display TabLayout.Below is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="7dp">
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:padding="2dp"
android:textSize="10dp" />
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:minWidth="40dp" android:background="@drawable/top_left" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="Civil Bank " android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"   android:minWidth="40dp" android:background="@drawable/top_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="Sunrise Bank" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:minWidth="40dp" android:background="@drawable/top_right"  android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
           <TextView android:text="Web user" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle"  android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="0.00" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/webuserTxtView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/> 
           <TextView  android:text="0.00" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/S_webuserTxtView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
           <TextView android:text="Transfer" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="0.00" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/transferTxtView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="0.00" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/S_transferTxtView"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
           <TextView android:text="Cash" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_right" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="0.00" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/cashTxtView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_middle" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
           <TextView android:text="0.00" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/S_cashTxtView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bottom_left" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
       </TableRow>



<TabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</TableLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the width and height of your `tablelayout` as `fill-parent`.So it would probably occupy the whole space of your `linearlayout`. Instead of `fill-parent` you have to use `wrap-content`. In  tabhost you use the property `android:layout_below="@+id/yourTableLayout"`.